# french spell checker api

Tags: java, spell-checking, languagetool

I'm working with extjs and Java EE and I have an extjs html xtype and I want to integrate a French spell checker API.

But I haven't any idea about APIs and how to integrate them.

Can any one give me some information about some example of an API and how to use it?

Comment: Write one yourself. It shouldn't be too hard. You'd need too calculate the levenshtein distance for each word in the text for each word in a list of all french words. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Comment: http://www.languagetool.org is an open source based java spell checking solution that you might want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) from Java. You can take the dictionary from OpenOffice/LibreOffice, look for `*.dic` and `*.aff` files. As OpenOffice/LibreOffice has many users, chances are good that the dictionary is well-maintained.